# How to sort order names with special characters on lists?

Tags: web-app, sorting, ordering

I'm working on a project that contains contacts (First name, Last name), and currently we're using ascending/descending to allow users to re-order the list, however, I'm facing a problem with treating special characters, since they are represented first in the ordering. Should I present them at the last? should I keep them first? What is the most advised experience here?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you ignore special characters and sort them based only on alphabetical characters?

Comment: That would result in users not finding the entries at the position they are looking for.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/39390)

Comment: If the special characters are part of the names I will delete my answer. I thought that there are random special characters just like in nick names.

Comment: I like this answer - as further clarification it would mean that "!AB" would appear before "AB" but after "AA"

Comment: @mayo I think the question here is rhetorical.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for the interaction,
I can't ignore special characters because some of the names contains these characters. I guess my question is not very specific, maybe it would be if i asked: is there a specific UX experience advised to treat ordering with special characters? and does it treat special characters to be first or last on the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

That also depends on language specifics. e.g. if you sort asc/desc in MySQL databases you can define a collation in which the textual data are given. German speaking users would sort differently form english speaking users.